# Non singularity of strict diagonally dominant real matrices

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

Let $A=(a_{i,j})$ be an $n \times n$ strict diagonally dominant real matrix, then prove that $$||Ay||_{\infty}\geq \delta_{\min}||y||_{\infty}, ~\forall y \in \mathbb R^ n$$ where, $$\delta_{\min}=\min_{i}\left\{|a_{i,i}|-\sum_{j=1, j\neq i}^{n}|a_{i,j}|\right\}$$

\begin{array} { l } { \textbf{ My attempt:- } } \\ { \text { Let } A = \left( \begin{array} { c c c } { a _ { 11 } } & { \ldots } & { a _ { 1 n } } \\ { \vdots } & { } & { \vdots } \\ { a _ { n 1 } } & { \cdots } & { a _ { n n } } \end{array} \right) , y = \left( \begin{array} { c } { y _ { 1 } } \\ { \vdots } \\ { y _ { n } } \end{array} \right) } \end{array}

$$\Rightarrow \left\| A  y \right\| _ { \infty } = \max _ { i } \left\{ \left| \sum _ { j = 1 } ^ { n } a _ { i j } y _ { j } \right| \right\}$$
$$\delta _ { \min } \| y \| _ { \infty } = \min _ {i} \left\{ \left| a _ { i,i} \right| \| y \| _ { \infty } - \left( \sum _ { j = 1 \atop j \neq 1 } ^ { n } \left| a _ { i j } \right| \right) \|y \| _ { \infty } \right\}$$
\begin{array} { r } { \leq \left| a _ { ii } \cdot \right| \| y \| _ { \infty } - \left| a _ { i 1 } \right| \left| y _ { 1 } \right| - \left| a _ { i 2 } \right| | y | _ { 2 } } \\ { - \cdots - \left| a _ { i n } \right| \left| y _ { n } \right| } \\ { \text { Now how to proceed. } } \end{array}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By scaling we only have to prove that $\|Ax\|_\infty\ge\delta$ for all $x$ with $\|x\|_\infty = 1$. Hence, let $x\in\mathbb R^n$ with $\|x\|_\infty=1$. Then $x_k = \pm 1$ for some $k$ and thus
$$
\left|\sum_ja_{kj}x_j\right| = \left|\pm a_{kk} + \sum_{j\neq k}a_{kj}x_j\right|\,\ge\,|a_{kk}| - \left|\sum_{j\neq k}a_{kj}x_j\right|\,\ge\,|a_{kk}| - \sum_{j\neq k}|a_{kj}||x_j|\,\ge\,\delta.
$$